# DHIS2 Live Install Problem - HTTP Error 503 - Windows 10 Home v10

Tags: error, dhis2, http-code-503

I am trying to install and use DHIS2 Live for a small project. I have followed the instructions in the latest DHIS2 Implementor Guide, and extracted the downloaded zipped file to my desktop. When I run the executable file, a tab opens in my browser with the following message:

> HTTP ERROR: 503 Problem accessing /. Reason: Service Unavailable Powered by Jetty://

Yesterday, I was able to reach the DHIS2 Live login screen (but could not login), but today I only get the aforementioned error message. Any guidance you can provide would be appreciated.

I am using the following hardware and software:

Laptop: Lenovo ideapad 300s
OS: Windows 10 Home v10 64-bit
Browser: Opera 45.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251518/jetty-http-error-503-service-unavailable

Comment: Could you please provide the output from the logs? Note that DHIS 2.29 does not work with the H2 database.